# GridView is displaying only one row

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to display a calendar in a GridView, which has been created view code (not XML).
But I am able to display only 1 line of the GridView and not all the lines.

I believe i am missing some properties or setting wrong properties:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Panel panel = new Panel(context);

    ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    mainScrollView.addView(panel);


class Panel extends LinearLayout {

    public Panel(Context context) {
         super();
         super.setMinimumHeight(400); //LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

         GridView view = new GridView(context);
         view.setMinimumHeight(400);  //(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
         view.setMinimumWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
         view.setColumnWidth(60);
         view.setNumColumns(7);
         view.setVerticalSpacing(10);
         view.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
         view.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
         view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

         view.setAdapter(new MYAdapter(context));
    }


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        super();

        //insert 30 elements into a list
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
    String str = list.get(position);
    textView.setText(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.toCharArray().length);
    if (convertView == null) {
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(65, 65));
        textView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    } else {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }
    return textView;
}
```

}

There is no difference if i set the Height to MATCH_PARENT or a specific number.

Comment: Please post your adapter and your onCreate, to show us how is it layed out and xml if any

Comment: view.setColumnWidth(80); try this may be help you.